# how do I create multiple modal boxes in a loop

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a personal portfolio website using just HTML/CSS/JS. Follows the grid template [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/grid-cats). I've included the additional functionality of opening a Modal box when the user clicks on each `article-class`, which are the `class="modal"` elements. Clicking to open, or clicking on the 'X' to close, is handled by JS. Just the `<body>`:

```
<body>
    <main>
        <section class="leading">
          <p class="leading-bigtext">Big Headline Text</p>
        </section>

        <section class="cards">
          <article id="article1" class="article-class">
            <img class="article-img" src="http://placekitten.com/305/205" alt=" " />
            <h1 class="article-title">
                Article Headline 1
            </h1>
          </article>

          <article id="article2" class="article-class">
            <img class="article-img" src="http://placekitten.com/320/220" alt=" " />
            <h1 class="article-title">
                Article Headline 2
            </h1>
          </article>

          <article id="article3" class="article-class">
            <img class="article-img" src="http://placekitten.com/280/250" alt=" " />
            <h1 class="article-title">
                Article Headline 3
            </h1>
          </article>

          <article id="article4" class="article-class">
            <img class="article-img" src="http://placekitten.com/430/240" alt=" " />
            <h1 class="article-title">
                Article Headline 4
            </h1>
          </article>
        </section>

      <!-- ==================== The Modals ==================== -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <h1>Article Title 1</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
          <a href="https://github.com/Don86/microscopy-image-analysis" target="_blank" class="tooltip">
            <img src="./assets/GitHub-Mark-120px-plus.png" height="32" width="32"/>
            <span class="tooltiptext">Link to Github repo</span>
        </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <h1>Article Title 2</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="myModal3" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <h1>Article Title 3</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="myModal4" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <h1>Article Title 4</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <script>
      var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
      var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');
      var modal3 = document.getElementById('myModal3');
      var modal4 = document.getElementById('myModal4');
      // Get the button that opens the modal
      var btn = document.getElementById("article1");
      var btn2 = document.getElementById("article2");
      var btn3 = document.getElementById("article3");
      var btn4 = document.getElementById("article4");
      // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
      var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
      var span3 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[2];
      var span4 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[3];

      // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
      btn.onclick = function() {modal.style.display = "block";}
      btn2.onclick = function() {modal2.style.display = "block";}
      btn3.onclick = function() {modal3.style.display = "block";}
      btn4.onclick = function() {modal4.style.display = "block";}
      // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
      span.onclick = function() {modal.style.display = "none";}
      span2.onclick = function() {modal2.style.display = "none";}
      span3.onclick = function() {modal3.style.display = "none";}
      span4.onclick = function() {modal4.style.display = "none";}
      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
      window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
      window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal2) {
          modal2.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
      window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal3) {
          modal3.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
      window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal4) {
          modal4.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    </script>
</body>
```

This works, but the `<script>` portion is ugly because it consists of a lot of repeated code. Every time I add a new `article`, I'd have to copy-paste the same lines of code again. I've tried using `for-loops` and `map`, but I must have not implemented things correctly, but in any case it's had to instantiate variables in a loop (without overriding the same variable over and over again). Is there a way to do this more elegantly?

The CSS for completeness:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,900i');

header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .leading {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
}

/* Grid styles */
.cards {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 30px;
  }

/* generic styles */
body {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

/*header class not used*/
header {
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.leading {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Playfair Display"
}

.leading-bigtext {
  margin-right: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .leading-bigtext {
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

.leading-text {
  max-width: 900px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

.cards {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
}

article {
  cursor: pointer; /* chance cursor to a hand to prompt click-thru */
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
}

article:hover {
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 4px #aaaaaa;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.article-img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.article-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

/* ==================== Modal css ==================== */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make modals unique to be able to select them later. One way to do this is through `id`.

```
<div id="modal-window-one" class="modal-window modal"></div>
<div id="modal-window-two" class="modal-window modal"></div>
```

You need to define which button which window should open. One possible solution for this is through `data-attributes`.

```
<div class="click-to-open" data-modal="modal-window-one"> //will open modal one
<div class="click-to-open" data-modal="modal-window-two"> //will open modal two
```

And then - event:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("click-to-open");

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  var thisBtn = btn[i];
  thisBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var modal = document.getElementById(this.dataset.modal);
    modal.style.display = "block";
}, false);
```

this is one of solutions.